# How to plot uncertainty bounds of a set of curves where each curve has inconsistent time steps

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Suppose we have a set of sequences of discrete points. Each has different horizontal value (say timesteps), then what is the best way to plot the uncertainty bounds over those curves described by discrete sampled points.

More concretely, let us define the following two curves (with their discrete points)

```
x1 = [1, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 20]
y1 = [0.1, 0.25, 0.22, 0.53, 0.37, 0.5, 0.55]
x2 = [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 15]
y2 = [0.03, 0.12, 0.4, 0.2, 0.18, 0.32, 0.39]
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x2, y2, 'red')
```

And we want to plot a smooth mean with uncertainty bounds with one standard deviation. 
[image]

In the plot above, the green and red curves are the real data, and shaded blue indicates the fitted uncertainty bands.

Comment: Do you want to plot the mean with the error bars? Your x values are not the same in the two lists so how would you define the mean? Can you show some desired output? Currently I don't understand how your final plot should look like

Answer (score 2):

If you want the std grayed around the mean, you can do it the following way. First put data together in a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

s1 = pd.Series(y1, index=x1).rename('s1')
s2 = pd.Series(y2, index=x2).rename('s2')

df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

# Now let's unstack the dataframe so seaborn can recognize it
data = df.unstack().dropna().to_frame()
data.columns = ['values']
```

Then the plot can be done like this:

```
ax = sns.lineplot(x='level_1', y = 'values', hue='level_0',
              data=data.reset_index())

# Fill the missing points using interpolation
df_filled = df.copy().interpolate()

ma = df_filled.mean(axis=1).interpolate()

ax.plot(ma.index, ma, color='r', linestyle='--', label='mean')

mstd = ma.std()

ax.fill_between(ma.index, ma + mstd, ma - mstd,
                color='b', alpha=0.2)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

**OLD SOLUTION**:
I found myself with a similar problem yesterday, and this is how I solved it applied to your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Convert the timeseries to pd.Serires

s1 = pd.Series(y1, index=x1).rename('s1')
s2 = pd.Series(y2, index=x2).rename('s2')

# Put all together in a dataframe

df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

>> df
      s1    s2
1   0.10   NaN
2    NaN  0.03
4   0.25  0.12
5   0.22   NaN
6    NaN  0.40
7   0.53  0.20
9   0.37  0.18
11   NaN  0.32
13  0.50   NaN
15   NaN  0.39
20  0.55   NaN
```

Then use [seaborn.pointplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html) adjusting the dataframe so it can be useful for setting the 'x', 'y' variables of seaborn.pointplot:

```
data = df.unstack().dropna().to_frame()
data.columns = ['values']

>> data.reset_index()

   level_0  level_1  values
0       s1        1    0.10
1       s1        4    0.25
2       s1        5    0.22
3       s1        7    0.53
4       s1        9    0.37
5       s1       13    0.50
6       s1       20    0.55
7       s2        2    0.03
8       s2        4    0.12
9       s2        6    0.40
10      s2        7    0.20
11      s2        9    0.18
12      s2       11    0.32
13      s2       15    0.39
```

Finally the result if plotting is this:

```
ax = sns.pointplot(x='level_1', y = 'values', ci='sd',
                   data=data.reset_index())

ax.set_xlabel('')
```

[image]

The middle point should be the mean value for that time-spot and the error bar is adjusted to be the 'sd' by default (you can the confidence interval in 'ci' to be a float also or remove it. More info at the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html)).